# php form not updating database

Tags: php, database

I am trying to use pdo to update a database, the code is not returning any errors but the code does not work.
Logic is the user would enter in user id and then a new location hit submit and the location would be updated.

Here is the form code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Web Dev 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="update.php">
            Patient location by ID: <input type="text" id="Patid" name="Patid" /><br />
            Location: <input type="text" id="Location" name="Location" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name = 'action' value="update" />
</html>
```

This is update code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    $host = "localhost";
    $user ="sbuser";
    $db = "mdb";
    $pass ="lamepassword";
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $sqlInsert = 'UPDATE lobby set Location=:Location where Patid=:Patid';
    $preparedStatement = $conn->prepare($sqlInsert);
    $preparedStatement->execute(array(':Patid' => '$_POST[Patid]', ':Location' = $_POST[Location]' );
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where is the initialization of $dsn ?

Comment: On a side note, your closing `</body>` is missing in the code sample.

Comment: thanku for that note... @dakab

Comment: That also applies to the closing `</form>` as well as unmatched curly brackets in your PHP code. There's already [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31770204/2083613) with further hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is some error in your code

```
<?php
 $host = "localhost";
 $db = "mdb";
 $user ="sbuser";
 $pass ="";
 $Patid=$_POST['Patid'];
 $Location=$_POST['Location'];
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;name=$name",$user,$pass);
    $sqlInsert = "UPDATE lobby SET Location=? WHERE Patid=?";
    $preparedStatement = $conn->prepare($sqlInsert);
    $preparedStatement->execute(array($Location, $Patid));
?>
```